# How can I have a common variable between two methods?

Tags: java, vector

```
boolean exists;
public void searchProduct(Vector <Stock> temp){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    sc.useDelimiter ("\n");
    exists = false;
    System.out.println ("Enter Product Name to Search for: ");
    String n = sc.next();
    System.out.println ();
    Stock s = null;
    if(temp.size() == 0)
        System.out.println ("Database is Empty! Please Add a Product.");
    else if (!n.matches(valn))
        System.out.println ("Invalid Product.Please Try Again.");
    else{
        for(int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i ++){
            s = temp.elementAt(i);
            if(s.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(n)){
                System.out.println(s.ToString());
                System.out.println ("Location: " + (i + 1));
                exists = true;
            }
        }
        if(exists != true)
            System.out.println ("Product Not Found!");
        System.out.println ("---------------------------------------------"); 
    } 
}

public void delProduct(Vector <Stock> temp){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    if(temp.size() == 0)
        System.out.println ("Database is Empty! Please Add a Product.");
    else{
        sc.useDelimiter("\n");
        Stock s = new Stock();
        int choice = 0;
        int i = 0;
        boolean quit = false;
        boolean valid = true; 
        s.searchProduct(temp);
        if(exists == true){ 
            do{
                try{
                    System.out.println ("Enter Location of Product to delete: ");
                    i = sc.nextInt();
                    temp.removeElementAt(i-1);
                    System.out.println ();
                    System.out.println ("Product was Deleted Succesfully!");
                    System.out.println ("--------------------------------"); 
                    valid = false;
                }catch(InputMismatchException ime){
                    sc.next();
                    System.out.println ("Invalid Location.");
                }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException a){
                    System.out.println ("Location does not Exist!");
                }
            }while(valid); 
        }
    }
}
```

As it is, everything works perfectly fine. But the thing is, that if the user enters a `product name` to delete that does not exist in the vector, he is still expected to enter the location to delete. (Obviously, it is doing what it is supposed to do).
I have tried declaring different boolean variables that are set to true if the search item is found, and the delete procedure is only executed if the boolean is true, but somehow the variable is always false in the delete method. Any ideas please? Btw, sorry if I make silly mistakes, I am still new to Java.

Comment: I recommend using more descriptive variable names: so your code will be easily read by other programmers. Declare the `n` variable outside the method.

Comment: @tomloprod I edited the code and inserted an `if-statement` in the `delete` method. However, the `exists` variable is always `false` in that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, when you do `s.searchProduct(temp)` you are expecting that `exists` to be true if the product is found but it is not the case. Because while you are doing `s.searchProduct(temp)`, you are calling method `searchProduct(temp)` from another `Stock` object that you called `s`. Therefore if the product exists in temp, then `exists` of `s` will be true, so `s.exists` will be true. However, what you want to be true is `this.exists`. For this, you have to replace `s.searchProduct(temp)` line with `this.searchProduct(temp)` or `searchProduct(temp)`.

Also as far as I understand from your code, in `delProduct` method you don't need to create a `Stock` object that you called `s`.

Furthermore, you can also do this delete job by first calling a `selectProduct(temp)` method which will return the location of the product. If the product doesn't exist, then it will return -1. Then, if the result of `searchProduct(temp)` method is not -1, use the returned location in a `deleteProduct(temp)` method. In this case, you won't bother with boolean flags to determine what to do when. Just another idea.

Good luck.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Also, thanks for that idea, didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

When you call s.searchProduct(temp), exists should become true or false based on whether it is found.  Have you verified that this is happening?  What is that valn variable you have in there?

Once that's working, you need to add a check within delete to check if exists is true and then ask for the location, otherwise to ask for more input (and then search again).

Comment: Yes the first part I have done it, and it works perfectly fine. Trying out the rest right now.

Comment: It is still being considered as false.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried declaring the variable exists as volatile or maybe static so that it shall remain global for the entire class. But it will have to accessed using the classname.